# Integral using the definition of integral is returning double the real answer?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to evaluate an integral using the definition of the definite integral but for some reason my answer is 12 when it should be 6. I assumed that I'd missed a 2 somewhere that would go in the denominator but I've tried this exercise multiple times and I keep getting the same answer.

My steps:

$$ \int_0^3 (2x-1)dx = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k(3-0)}{n}\right) \frac{3}{n} $$

First I solve the function that is inside the summation.
$$ f\left(\frac{k(3-0)}{n}\right) = f\left(\frac{3k}{n}\right) = 2\left(\frac{3k}{n}\right) - 1 = \frac{6k}{n} - 1 $$

Then I solve the summation.
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \frac{6k}{n} - 1 \right) \frac{3}{n} = \frac{3}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \frac{6k}{n} - 1 \right) = \frac{3}{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{6k}{n} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1) \right) = \frac{3}{n}\left( \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{6}{n}k \right) - (-n) \right) = \frac{3}{n}\left(\frac{6}{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}k \right) + n \right) = \frac{3}{n} \left( \frac{6}{n} \cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + n \right) = \frac{3}{n} \left( 3(n+1) + n \right) = \frac{3}{n}(4n + 3) = \frac{12n + 9}{n} $$

Then I find the limit of the solved summation as $n \to \infty$.
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{12n + 9}{n} = 12 $$

However, the answer should be 6. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You wrote $-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(-1)$ but it should be $-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n1$ or $+ \sum\limits_{k=1}^n(-1)$.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I made this mistake so many times in a row... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael said, it's just a sign error:
$$\cdots= \frac{3}{n} \left( \frac{6}{n} \cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \color{red}{-} n \right) = \frac{3}{n} \left( 3(n+1) \color{red}{-} n \right) = \frac{3}{n}(\color{red}{2}n + 3) = \frac{\color{red}{6}n + 9}{n}$$